# Mysql query to count number of links and divide resoults by status

Tags: mysql, count

I have a query to print out list of links (1 col) and their count (2nd). What I would like to do is to divide results by their status.

Example

[image: Sampel Table]

My Code: (Mysql, Php, Html)

```
$sql="SELECT `bookinglink`, count(`bookinglink`) AS 'count' 
FROM `quotedb` 
WHERE `bookinglink` != '' AND (status = 'quote' or status = 'booking')
GROUP BY `bookinglink` ORDER BY count DESC";

$result=$mysqli->query( $sql );
    while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $rs->bookinglink . "</td><td>" . $rs->count . "</td></tr>";
}
```

So i will need to make sure query counts all links and then counts links with status "quote" and "booking". Is it possible to make it work in one query?

Could you plaes help me to work it out, as I'm not so sure how to get on with it.

Comment: Sum (case when ... then... end) x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query could be written as follows:

```
SELECT bookinglink, COUNT(bookinglink) AS bookinglinkcount,
    SUM(status = 'quote') AS quotes,
    CAST(100 * SUM(status = 'quote') / COUNT(bookinglink) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) 
                          AS quotes_percentage,
    SUM(status = 'booking') AS bookings,
    CAST(100 * SUM(status = 'booking') / COUNT(bookinglink) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) 
                          AS bookings_percentage
FROM quotedb
    WHERE bookinglink != ''
GROUP BY bookinglink;
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/TYLV16443)